# Regex expression to separate collapsed title

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

First time post. I have a text where lots of text in title case is collapsed without spaces. I'm trying to:
a) keep the full text (not loose any words), 
b) use logic to separate 'A' as in 'A Way Forward',
c) avoid separating acronyms such as EPA, DOJ, ect (which are already in full caps).

My regex code comes pretty close, but it's leaving 'A' at the beginning or end of words:

f = "TheCuriousIncidentOfAManInAWhiteHouseAt1600PennsylvaniaAveAndTheEPA"

re.sub( r"([A-Z][a-z]|[A-Z][A-Z]|\d+)", r" \1", f).split()

output:

*['The', 'Curious', 'Incident', 'Of', 'AMan','In', 'AWhite','House', 'At', '1600', 'Pennsylvania', 'Ave', 'And', 'The', 'EPA']*

The problem is output like 'AMan', 'AWhite', ect.

It should be:

*['The', 'Curious', 'Incident', 'Of', **'A', Man',**'In', **'A', White',**'House', 'At', '1600', 'Pennsylvania', 'Ave', 'And', 'The', 'EPA']*

Thank you

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(?=$|[A-Z])|[A-Z][a-z]*|[^A-Za-z]+', s)`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5l8E1K/1).

Comment: @Wiktor, this is excellent, but one small problem due to my own wording. The text also includes normal text that I don't want to lose. For example:
f = "TheCuriousIncidentOfAManInAWhiteHouseAt1600PennsylvaniaAveAndTheEPA. This is how the story begins. On a fateful..."

So the output should also include, 'This', 'is', 'how', 'the', 'story', 'begins' and so on. Punctuation isn't important, but the word should be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Greg. Good start on your regex.

I'd try something like this:

```
([A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[a-zA-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+)
```

Broken down, for explanation:

```
([A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])  // 2 or more capital letters, not followed by a lowercase letter
|                    // OR
[a-zA-Z][a-z]*       // Any letter, followed by any number of lowercase letters
|                    // OR
[0-9]+)              // One or more digits
```

Best used like this:

```
re.findall(r'([A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[a-zA-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+)', s)
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/5l8E1K/5) (contains `\W*` for formatting)

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks for the extra explanations and link. Very helpful for me as a regex beginner!